# How to restrict access to a woocommerce shop?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I've tried to look everywhere but I can't seem to find anyone else who has had a similar issue, so if you ever stumbled across one, please refer me to it!

So my situation is the following: I am trying to implement a WooCommerce Shop into an existing WordPress site. What I want to do now is to restrict access to all shop pages to one group of people but without implementing anything authentication like. So no password entry or anything like that. Since the restriction doesn't NEED to be that safe, the idea that stuck to me most was using PHPs HTTP_REFERER and placing a link to the shop on a website that only the members have access to and then only letting those enter that clicked a link to the shop on that site by checking their referrer. The exact problem now is, that I cannot find the right location to place the query in the code. I'd need to find a place in the code that always runs when any WooCommerce Shop page gets loaded, but also only then. There I could then always check if the user came in by clicking the link on the said website. And probably also if the user is coming from a different shop page.

I really have no idea how to achieve this, so if anyone of you has an idea, I would really appreciate any help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Define: `[...] restrict access to all shop pages to one group of people` ? What do you mean by group ? How do you define group, do you mean WordPress Roles ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! By group of people I basically mean members that are allowed to enter the shop. We already have a separate platform on which our members can log in and my plan was to place a link to the shop there and then, on the Wordpress page, check if the user actually came from that platform! Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the referrer is not always defined. (eg: Using a bookmark or directly visiting the website through the url).

Ignoring the first statement, there is a few other things we need to consider.

The referrer will be emptied out as soon as you navigate away from the referred page. Which would trigger an infinite redirect loop. A solution would be to redirect all traffic to the login page if the user is not logged-in, and redirect the login page to the refferer website if the referrer is empty.

```
<?php

/**
 * Redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in and not on a login page.
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {

    $request_uri = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! strpos( basename( $request_uri ), 'wp-login.php' ) ) {

        wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    
        exit;

    };

} );

/**
 * Redirect the user to the refferer page if the refferer is not defined.
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
add_action( 'login_init', function () {

    $refferer = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_REFERER', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! empty( $refferer ) && false !== strpos( $refferer, 'https://...' ) ) { //https://... points to the refferer site.

        wp_redirect( 'https://...' ); //https://... points to the refferer site.
    
        exit;

    };

} );
```

On a side note, Even tho this should be exactly what you asked for, I do not recommend the following approach. This is anything but secure (eg: Referrer spoofing).